# Mayavi mlab savefig crops text

Tags: python, enthought, mayavi

Whenever I try to do savefig with magnification > 1 the text3d inside the figure gets cropped. So I can see the saver running through my figure and I realize that text actors that lie in different tiles get cropped. Any fix for that? On the picture it should be laser pulse not puls, and I haven't misspelled it
[image]

Comment: I have encountered this bug before.  There really is no simple fix.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, looking over the recent changes, this bug has been fixed recently in the development version of mayavi but has not been propagated to any releases yet.  But I downloaded the source from github and this behavior now works correctly.

Comment: so the latest version? Thanks for helping.